# Fastest way to compute angle between 2D vectors

Tags: python, numpy, vector, numpy-ndarray

I'm looking for efficient alternate ways to compute cosine angle between 2D vectors. Your insights on this problem will be of much help.

### Problem Statement:

`vectors` is a 2D array where vectors are stored. The shape of the `vectors` array is `(N, 2)` where `N` is the number of vectors. `vectors[:, 0]` has x-component and `vectors[:, 1]` has y-component.

I have to find the angle between all the vectors in `vectors`. For example, if there are three vectors A, B, C in `vectors`, I need to find the angle between `A and B`, `B and C`, and, `A and C`.

I have implemented it and wants to know alternative ways.

### Current Implementation:

```
vectors = np.array([[1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 5]])

vec_x = vectors[:, 0]
vec_y = vectors[:, 1]

a1 = np.ones([vec_x.shape[0], vec_x.shape[0]]) * vec_x
a2 = np.ones([vec_x.shape[0], vec_x.shape[0]]) * vec_y
a1b1 = a1 * a1.T
a2b2 = a2 * a2.T
mask = np.triu_indices(a1b1.shape[0], 0) # We are interested in lower triangular matrix
a1b1[mask] = 0
a2b2[mask] = 0
numer = a1b1 + a2b2
denom = np.ones([vec_x.shape[0], vec_x.shape[0]]) * np.sqrt(np.square(a1) + np.square(a2))
denom = denom * denom.T
denom[mask] = 0
eps = 1e-7
dot_res = np.rad2deg(np.arccos(np.divide(numer, denom + eps)))
dot_res[mask] = 0
print(dot_res)
```

### Output:

```
[[ 0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 8.13010519  0.          0.        ]
 [12.52880911  4.39870821  0.        ]]
```

### Questions:

1. Is there any alternative way to do this more efficient?
2. Can we improve the speed of the current version in some way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial.distance

vectors = np.array([[1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 5]])
# Compute cosine distance
dist = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(vectors, 'cosine')
# Compute angles
angle = np.rad2deg(np.arccos(1 - dist))
# Make it into a matrix
angle_matrix = scipy.spatial.distance.squareform(angle)
print(angle_matrix)
# [[ 0.          8.13010235 12.52880771]
#  [ 8.13010235  0.          4.39870535]
#  [12.52880771  4.39870535  0.        ]]
```